# Is a 100MHz oscilloscope good enough for SPI, UART, I2C and CAN?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, oscilloscope, can

I am having trouble with microcontrollers (STM32s mainly) on custom PCBs. I want to get an oscilloscope to help me solve these issues. Naturally budget is small so I want to know is if a 100 MHz oscilloscope with 1 gigasamples good enough for to help me debug.

I'm not doing anything too fancy, just general IO, power supplies, low speed SPI, UART, I2C and CAN. I  have a cheap logic analyzer so that's taken care of.

Comment: For debugging serial buses and the like, that's good enough. Higher frequency scopes are mainly useful for RF signals. Best advice I can give otherwise is to _not_ cheap out and buy some Chinese brand. That's what I did last time and I regret it, because the product quality is overall poor and the fan is so loud I'm just waiting for it to take off. Be prepared to spend somewhere between $1k - $2k for decent quality.

Comment: Whether or not a 100 MHz scope is good enough for your purpose is an opinion we can't know. It depends what problems you are having with them. Certanly a 100 MHz scope better than no scope at all. But as buses tend to have digital logic signals, a 100 MHz scope can't see a 20 MHz square wave as square wave any more as it can only see first 3 harmonics, it might be good for signals less than 10 MHz. Many MCUs, UARTs and SPI buses run faster than that.

Comment: Calvin, the cheapest stuff is noisy, funky, and won't meet the specs they tell you about. But a dual channel with signal generation and multimeter is under USD80 (The Zoyi ZT-703S.) And battery-powered, which can be handy. The next step up may be Rigol or a Digilent unit. Both are good quality. But now up around USD300-USD500. Used, consider analog scopes from Tektronix. Or the HP 54645D MSO from HP. If you can afford high sample rates then by all means get one. I really do believe you should buy as much as you can afford to buy. And if you can consider it, then get an MSO.

Comment: Calvin, But given your question -- sure, 100 MHz oscilloscope is enough for any of those protocols, so far as I can recall needing. I usually use an MSO for things like this. But I have used my 2245A 100 MHz Tek scope with success in every case I've applied it in cases you suggest. So 100 MHz should be okay.

Comment: Don't forget update rate. HP, who sells high update rate scopes, made a nice appnote about why you should buy a high update rate scope. https://www.es-france.com/index.php?controller=attachment&id_attachment=8949

Comment: Thanks all, appreciate the advice!

Comment: In the budget range, you can get a used basic Tek in 200MHz, with few features (but limited need to use the menus, actually more pleasant UI arguably), or a somewhat newer Siglent with way more features. I'd skip Rigol entirely. My 2cents. Also depending on what you're doing, in particular a 4 channel may be quite useful. Here a low-shelf brand with modern digital features might be nice, if it has logic analyzer modes.

Comment: @periblepsis Rigol have awful quality. We invested in some 6 units, some high end for R&D and some low end for production troubleshooting. They have all manner of strange hiccups like the display glitching, or EMI getting picked up from who-knows-where. And as mentioned, the fans sound like an attack helicopter ready to take off. That being said, it doesn't have to be Tektronix premium scopes either. R&S (previously Hameg) have good quality scopes in the mid range, for example.

Comment: @Lundin That's a separate subject. I was just mentioning "steps" from the top of my head. Glad to hear about better choices!

Comment: It is definitely enough. I have been debugging serial comms with a cheap 20MHz USB scope for years before I got a proper scope. It of course depends on the communication frequency. As long as the scope has at least 2x (ideally you'd want about 10x though) sampling frequency than what you are measuring, you will see it. If it's outside the scope bandwidth, it will be attenuated but still likely readable. Keep in mind that sampling rate and bandwidth are two separate scope parameters.